# Java Text String: Want Only One Word In Bold

Tags: java

I have a string in a textbox and want only one of the words to be in bold.  Is there a way to do that in code without appending the text? Sort of like how it would be done in xml/html...  How about an underline, too?

Prefer not using xml or html for this - prefer to keep it a string in java code...

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to add some information, e.g. exactly what control are you using - this is Java right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Swing components already [understand a subset of HTML](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) as long as you surround the text in `<html>...</html>`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a JTextPane with attributes:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Define a keyword attribute

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

//  Change attributes on some text

doc.setCharacterAttributes(4, 3, keyWord, false);
```